# Why this pattern only match the first and the last

Tags: regex

haystack:

```
<h2 >a&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;
</h2>
<div class="indent">
aaaa
</div>
<h2 >b&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;
</h2>
<div class="indent">
bbbb
</div>
```

pattern I used:

```
#<h2[^>]*>(a|b)(?!</h2>)[\s\S]*</h2><div class="indent">((?!</div>)[\s\S]+)</div>#
```

this pattern only matches the first h2 content(e.g. `a&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;`) and the content in last div(e.g. `bbbb`)

but I whan it to match all content in the h2 and div to make an one to one map(e.g. `a&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;`=>`aaaa`,`b&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;`=>`bbbb`), how do I do this?

Comment: c.c regex should never be used to parse html.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse it :), i'm making a spider... what else should i use to make one?

Comment: It should match none, as there is a newline after every `</h2>`... or did you alter your 'haystack'?

Comment: @Daedalus: Regex is a perfectly good tool for parsing HTML, if you don't need to *fully* parse HTML, and your needs are simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s\S]*` and `[\s\S]+` are greedy, meaning they will match as many characters as possible.  Try changing them to `[\s\S]*?` and `[\s\S]+?`.

With your current regex, if you were to put your `[\s\S]*` into a capturing group you would see that it matches the following:

```
&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;
</h2>
<div class="indent">
aaaa
</div>
<h2 >b&nbsp; &middot;&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;&middot;
```

Adding the `?` at the end makes this lazy, so instead of matching as much as possible it will match as few characters as possible, so it will stop at the first `</h2>` like you want.  The same reasoning applies to the `[\s\S]+` later in your regex.

It also looks like this should fail on your sample string because you have `</h2><div...` in the middle of your regex, but in your sample text there is always a newline between the closing `</h2>` and the `<div>`, you should probably change this section to `</h2>\s*<div...`.  End result:

```
#<h2[^>]*>(a|b)(?!</h2>)[\s\S]*?</h2>\s*<div class="indent">((?!</div>)[\s\S]+?)</div>#
```

[But don't parse HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505154)

Comment: it works! thank you. And thanks for your reminding, but is crawling in the range of 'parse'? If I don't use regex to make a crawler then what should i use?

Comment: @Wasabi You should use an HTML parser that someone else has already written and done correctly.